# How to change the data in a UITableView in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In the iPhone music app, it has a button at the middle of the screen for viewing the music library data in various ways. when clicked, a drop down menu appears with these options: Songs, Artists, Albums, Genre...and whenever any of this option is selected a table view changes it list to match the selection. I would like to implement this, any suggestion on how this could be implemented. How to change the data source of a TableView to display another data type by the click of a button.
[image: a screen shot of the music app]

Comment: This is too broad. What specifically do you need help with? Do you know how to respond to a button? Do you know how to use a table view in general?

Comment: yes I do, i want to change data in a UITable view on a button action

Comment: If you do know how to do those things, then what is your question?

Comment: When I click a button to make a selection from a menu, do i just change the tableview data source to make it display for instance list of albums instead of list of artists or songs that was showing before?

Comment: You either change the data source or you update the data used by the data source.

Answer (score 0):

Load your data in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _tableDataArray = @[@"One"];
}
```

Then update your data and call `reloadData` on the `tableView` after in code:

```
...
self.tableDataArray = @[@"One", @"Two"];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```